# why multiprocessing.Process is slower in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Hei i am trying to run a program on in serial on one single process and then on 4 processes using multiprocessing.Process in python. the goal with using this module is to speed up my program to comparison purposes with a project in my school.
i dont understand why i get it slower on multiprocessing version.

this is my code to run in serial:

```
import os

print('Implementing Matrix multiplication serial on one process \n')

A = [[1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3],
    [3,3,3,3]]

B = [[1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3],
    [3,3,3,3]]

for x in range(4):

    def matrixMul(A,B):

        for i in range(4):

            for j in range(4):

                for k in range(4):
                    result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]

        for r in result:
            print(r)
        process_id=os.getpid()
        print ("The process ID:",process_id)
    result = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
    matrixMul(A,B)
```

and here is the when using multi processes:

```
import os

import multiprocessing

print('Implementing Matrix multiplication parallely on 4 
processes \n')


A = [[1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3],
    [3,3,3,3]]

B = [[1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3],
    [3,3,3,3]]

def matrixMul(A,B):

    for i in range(4):

        for j in range(4):

            for k in range(4):
                result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]

    for r in result:
        print(r)
    process_id=os.getpid()
    print ("The process ID:",process_id)
result = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

jobs = []

for x in range(4):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=matrixMul, args=(A,B))
    p.start()
    jobs.append(p)

for proc in jobs:
    proc.join()
```

please help me to get clear answer because iam beginner in python
here is the results:

```
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509

real    0m0,022s
user    0m0,018s
sys     0m0,004s
```

and result from the multi one:

```
[9, 9, 9, 9] 
[18, 18, 18, 18] 
[27, 27, 27, 27] 
[27, 27, 27, 27] 
The process ID: 22511
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22512
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22513
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22514

real    0m0,069s
user    0m0,056s
sys     0m0,049s
```

Comment: Which operating system? Spawning OS's like windows need to create a new python instance per process which can be slower. Considering that your code does not use an `if __name__ == "__main__":` to protect itself from running the module level code in the subprocess, this is likely linux or mac, but best to be explicit. It would also be useful to time both and post the result, so we can see the difference.

Comment: I ran your code on my linux machine and parallel beat serial. However, run time in either case was very small. The dominant time consumer is the status prints. You should take those out when benchmarking.

Comment: @tdelaney i am using linux debian,  i have tried that with if __name__ == "__main__": also but no change

Comment: Running again, serlai beat parallel - must have been something else in the background. I think that since the operation is so short, the cost of forking isn't justified.

Comment: Here is the results: [9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22509

real    0m0,022s
user    0m0,018s
sys     0m0,004s

Comment: [9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22511
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22512
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22513
[9, 9, 9, 9]
[18, 18, 18, 18]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
[27, 27, 27, 27]
The process ID: 22514

real    0m0,069s
user    0m0,056s
sys     0m0,049s

Comment: The timings will vary system-to-system -- how slow terminal I/O is, f/e, matters a lot. If you want multiprocessing to help, you need to have a slow enough process (with a small enough amount of data needing to be serialized/deserialized) that the gains overcome the overhead.

Comment: ...there _are_ always costs -- spawning off subprocesses takes time (not a lot, but some). If that takes more time than parallelization saves, your program gets slower instead of faster, and that's normal. Make your matrix much, _much_, **much** larger and then multiprocessing might be faster; this one is so tiny that the cost of creating a subprocess is much more than the work you're creating the subprocesses to do.

Comment: Where did you get the real, user, and sys time from? The cprofiler? That might be causing the issue too because it'll need to attach itself to the forked process and makes spawning a new process slower.

Comment: @lalo can you specify which **command** you ran to get the result? Just saying it's from Linux isn't helping here (you used a profiler? kernel extension? something else?).

Comment: used "time" command in linux

Comment: I solved the problem by another way, i used os.fork() method 4 times to get samme effekt but with shorter time.